# Question on evaluation of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

how would one proceed to evaluate the sum of the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{n\times2^n}{(n+2)!}$

I am complete stuck and have no idea where to even start. All help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$\frac{n2^n}{(n+2)!} = \frac{2^n}{(n+1)!} - \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}$$
to compute the sum as a telescopic sum.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It was easy to derive after using the identity you mentioned